# How to send mails to a list of users using C#?

Tags: c#, email

I'm trying to send mails to a list of users according to the user Email property.
What i wish to do is simple: When a user delete his account from the site, an email will be sent to the list of admins of that site.

**EmailService**:

```
public MailMessage SendRemoveUserCompanyEmail(User user, List<User> admins, Company company, bool onParallelThread = true)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.From = new MailAddress(_configurationService.EmailFrom);
        foreach (string email in admins.Select(u => u.Email))
        {
        mail.To.Add(email);
        }
        mail.Subject = $"{_configurationService.AppName} - Closed account";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SetupImageEmail(mail, _TEMPLATE_MAIL_RESET_PASSWORD_IMAGE, out string imageContentID);

        string mailMessage = _fileService.GetTemplateMail(_TEMPLATE_MAIL_REMOVE_USER_COMPANY);
        mailMessage = mailMessage.Replace("##IMAGE_URL##", imageContentID);
        mailMessage = mailMessage.Replace("##COMPANY_NAME##", company.Name);
        mailMessage = mailMessage.Replace("##USER_NAME##", user.Name);
        mailMessage = mailMessage.Replace("##USER_SURNAME##", user.Surname);
        mailMessage = mailMessage.Replace("##PORTAL_URL##", _configurationService.BaseDomainClient);
        mailMessage = mailMessage.Replace("##PORTAL_NAME##", _configurationService.AppName);

        mail.Body = mailMessage;

        this.SendEmail(mail, onParallelThread);

        return mail;
    }
```

**UserService**:

```
public void DeleteUserCompany(User user, bool sendRejectMessage)
    {
        int? FK_Company = user.FK_Company;

        user.FK_Company = null;

        user.Company = null;

        user.Status = Status.FREE;


        UpdateEntityProperties(user, true, new string[] { "FK_Company", "Company", "Status" });

        Company company = null;
        if (FK_Company.HasValue)
        {
            company = _companyService.Get(FK_Company.Value);
        }

        if (sendRejectMessage)
        {
            _emailService.SendStopCollaborationEmail(user, company);

            _notificationService.SendNotification("Collaborazione interrotta Centro di assistenza", "Closed account", FK_Company, null, new List<int> { user.ID });
        }
        else
        {
            if (FK_Company.HasValue)
            {

                List<User> admins = _ctx.Users.Where(u => u.FK_Company == FK_Company && u.Role == Role.ADMIN).ToList();
                _emailService.SendRemoveUserCompanyEmail(user, admins, company);
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem is that admins don't receive anything. The list of mails are correctly populated in the **To** and all seems good, in the "return **mail**" i have the **To** correctly populated with mails but in the end the admins don't receive mails. I don't get it.

Mails are correct and working, no typing errors and not marked as spam.

Comment: Have you checked in the email server if the emails are blocked there? Could be that the emails are marked as spam and held in quarantine.

Comment: Yes  and unfortunately the spam is empty. The only difference between this mail and the others is that in this case I'm trying to send mails to a List instead of a single User

Comment: Refactor this then to send multiple mails in a loop, with each email having exactly one recipient. This way you will reduce this nonworking scenario to the other which you belive should work. Depending on the outcome of this refactoring, you decide what to do next.